# calling a function inside a function inside a function and so on... for n times in python

Tags: python

I am currently working on a mandelbrot set in the python.
Now I want to make a function which calls a function inside a function(and so on) for n times.
like,

1st loop: f(x)

2nd loop: f(f(x))

3rd loop: f(f(f(x)))

and so on...

now I made this code.

```
def f(x):
    return x**2

def g(x,n): 
    if n == 0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        f(g(x,n-1))

g(2,5)
```

Now I'm expecting the result f(f(f(f(f(2))))).
and it has an error,"Pow: 'NoneType' and 'int'".

how can I fix it? And is this a proper method of doing it?

Comment: Do you mean recursion?

Comment: show the code you've tried, the problem you have and the expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, you miss my answer, please check my answer. And your boundary is not  very right I think, should be n == 1 I think.

Comment: if I give you g(2,1), then your function output is f(f(2)) which is not meant to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(n):
    x = f(x)
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def g(x,n): 
    if n == 0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        f(g(x,n-1))
```

Else branch is missing `return` statement. So function does not return there, but instead continues until end of function body. And there is no return statement there either, so function returns None.

This is why you get the error you get.

Simply add `return` to else branch to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recusive method:

```
def g(x,n):
    if n == 1 :
         return f(x)
    elif n > 1:
         return f(g(x,n-1))
```

Or just like this:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    x = f(x)
print x
```